# Supposed solution for the Poisson equation fulfills Laplace equation instead.

Tags: partial-differential-equations, greens-function, poissons-equation

It seems basic, but I never understood properly. Suppose a spherical symmetric mass distribution, and a point outside the sphere. The gravitational field at the point can be calculated by summing all mass elements:$$\Phi = \int -\frac{Gdm}{|\mathbf r - \mathbf r'|} = \int -\frac{G\rho}{|\mathbf r - \mathbf r'|}dV$$ It is also the standard solution for the Poisson equation according to [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Poisson%27s_equation), where $f = -4\pi G\rho$.

Solving the integral, we get $$\Phi = -\frac{Gm}{r}$$ where m is the mass of the sphere and $r$ the distance to its center.
But the Laplacian of this solution is zero. It fulfills the Laplace equation (where $f = 0$) and not the Poisson's (where $f = -4\pi G\rho$).

I think that it can the mathematical translation for the fact that if all mass were at a singularity (the center), the field would be the same. In this case $\rho(\mathbf r) = 0$ everywhere. But anyway there is the problem of the singularity where $\rho(\mathbf 0) = \infty$.

How to deal with this anomaly?

Answer (score 1):

What do we know? We have a body, WLOG centered at the origin, with radius $R$, say. For simplicity, let's assume the body is small and dense enough (i.e, Mercury) for us to consider the mass distribution to be totally even. In other words,
$$\rho(r)=\begin{cases}\rho &r\leq R \\0 & r>R \end{cases}$$
As we are aware, the potential $U$ satisfies
$$\Delta U=4\pi G\rho$$
Outside the body, the density is zero, which reduces this to
$$\Delta U_{\text{out}}=0$$
I'll let you check on your own that this is solved by
$$U_{\text{out}}(r)=b_1+\frac{b_2}{r}$$
On the other hand, inside the body, the density is nonzero, so we have
$$\Delta U_{\text{in}}=4\pi G\rho$$
Once again, I will let you check for yourself that this is solved by
$$U_{\text{in}}(r)=a_1+\frac{a_2}{r}+\frac{2\pi G\rho r^2}{3}$$
As of now, we don't have enough information to uniquely specify the potential. We apply some physical conditions, imposing

- $U$ is well-defined at the origin
- And in particular $U(0)=0$. In physical terms, this means that it takes no work to move a particle at the origin, to the origin.
- $U_{\text{in}}(R)=U_{\text{out}}(R)$, in other words, the inside and outside potential agree on the body's surface

You'll notice that these are only three conditions, but we have *four* unknown constants. This is fine - the thing we are truly interested in is the graviational field, $\boldsymbol g$ which is related to the potential via
$$\boldsymbol g=-\nabla U$$
Because of this differentiation, we have some freedom up to shifting by a constant. So, we can, without loss of generality, decide to set $b_1=0$. The first two conditions impose $a_1=a_2=0$ so this reduces to
$$U_{\text{in}}(r)=\frac{2\pi G\rho r^2}{3} \\ U_{\text{out}}(r)=\frac{b_2}{r}$$
Applying the matching condition, you can deduce
$$b_2=\frac{2\pi G\rho R^3}{3}$$
And so
$$\boxed{U(r)=\begin{cases}\frac{2\pi G\rho r^2}{3} & r\leq R \\ \frac{2\pi G\rho R^2}{3}\frac{R}{r}& r>R \end{cases}}$$

Comment: If we can say that the equation is homogeneous ($f=0$) because density is zero outside, we can say the same inside a small void inside the sphere. But in this case $f=-4\pi G\rho$.

Comment: What do you mean by a "small void"??